# How to find critical point(s) for this f(x,y)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm asked to find the absolute maximum and minimum values of f(x,y) on the set D in this multivariate calculus problem:
f(x,y) = 1 + 4x -5y   and D is the closed triangular region with vertices (0,0), (2,0) and (3,0).

I'm at a loss of how to start this problem because I thought the first step was get the critical point(s) and I thought that was done by solving the system of equations from the partial derivatives.

However, when I find the partial with respect to x I get just 4, and the partial with respect to y = -5. So, doesn't make sense to me to try to solve this system of equations, unless it would just be (4,-5) and that's not how the book proceeds.

So, I'm stuck with not even knowing the critical point.

Comment: The region D does not look like a triangle to me, it looks like a straight line.Are you sure you have got $D$ correctly?

Comment: the book does have it exactly like this, but i'm guessing the 3rd point is (0,3)

Comment: even with the correct D values, how do I go about getting the cp when the partials are just constants?